# What would be an appropriate MySQL type for an e-mail?

Tags: mysql, email, database-design

I'm storing emails in MySQL database. What would be an appropriate type for an email? Should it be `VARCHAR(100)` because emails aren't that long? Or `VARCHAR(255)` to make sure emails longer than 100 chars fit, too? What if an email is longer than 255 chars? Maybe I should use `TEXT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emails are limited to a maximum of 254 characters, so VARCHAR(255) is your safest bet.